# OperationBehaviorAttribute inheritance

Tags: wcf

I have base class for my services. Attribute OperationBehavior doesn't apply if it defined in base class and I override method in derived class. Of cause, I can duplicate code, but maybe there is other way...

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class MyServiceBase
    {
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public virtual void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MyService : MyServiceBase, IMyService
    {
        public override void DoWork()
        {
            //No Transaction, because attribute OperationBehavior doesn't apply.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something like the following:

```
public class MyServiceBase
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        DoWorkImpl();
    }

    protected virtual DoWorkImpl()
    {
    }
}

public class MyService : MyServiceBase, IMyService
{
    protected override void DoWorkImpl()
    {
        //Should have a Tx here now
    }
}
```